# d3.js Double-click is not Releasing Nodes

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am attempting to convert a force-directed graph from d3 v3 to v4. My project is here:

https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/337d113cb77c3695ac6959bebe728795

Why isn't the double-click action on the nodes releasing the node back into the normal force layout? The drag and pin related functions are directly below the node code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set the `d.fx` and `d.fy` properties, the nodes will not move regardless of `d.fixed`. You set those properties here:

```
function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}
```

From the d3v4 API documentation:

> To fix a node in a given position, you may specify two additional
>   properties:
>
> ```
> fx - the node’s fixed x-position
> fy - the node’s fixed y-position
> ```
>
> At the end of each tick, after the application of any forces, a node
>   with a defined node.fx has node.x reset to this value and node.vx set
>   to zero; likewise, a node with a defined node.fy has node.y reset to
>   this value and node.vy set to zero. To unfix a node that was
>   previously fixed, set node.fx and node.fy to null, or delete these
>   properties.

I didn't read this prior to making [a demo](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/5443ecae4c53fdf6bc5e62799e3098e7) forked from your block, but the effect is the same: I set the `d.fx` and `d.fy` properties to undefined on double click, which allows them to be positioned according to the force diagram.

The reason you might see use of d.fixed to fix positions is this is the method used in v3:

> fixed - a boolean indicating whether node position is locked.

Comment: Thank you, again. Apologies for the (I'm sure) easy questions. Do you know of any good d3 v4 books or resources that compliment the API documentation?

Comment: I haven't seen much in the way of books. Personally I've largely been dependent on Mikes bl.ocks (the API documentation usually links to them) for the clean and canonical examples which I then mess with, the API documentation, Stackoverflow, and early on I used a lot of d3noob's explanations and examples. One of the important distinctions in resources is ensuring that you aren't looking at the wrong version since so much still uses v3, but the namespace changed in v4 (along with a significant number of other things).